# Force fact-gathering on all hosts

Tags: ansible, limit, hosts, ansible-facts

I'm sitting in front of a fairly complex Ansible project that we're using to set up our local development environments (multiple VMs) and there's one role that uses the facts gathered by Ansible to set up the `/etc/hosts` file on every VM. Unfortunately, when you want to run the playbook for one host only (using the -limit parameter) the facts from the other hosts are (obviously) missing.

Is there a way to force Ansible to gather facts on all hosts, even if you limit the playbook to one specific host?

We tried to add a play to the playbook to gather facts from all hosts, but of course that also gets limited to the one host given by the -limit parameter. If there'd be a way to force this play to run on all hosts before the other plays, that would be perfect.

I've googled a bit and found the solution with fact caching with redis, but since our playbook is used locally, I wanted to avoid the need for additional software. I know, it's not a big deal, but I was just looking for a "cleaner", Ansible-only solution and was wondering, if that would exist.

Answer (score 39):

Ansible version 2 introduced a clean, official way to do this using delegated facts (see: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#delegated-facts).

`when: hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4'] is not defined` is a check to ensure you don't check for facts in a host you already know the facts about

```
---
# This play will still work as intended if called with --limit "<host>" or --tags "some_tag"

- name: Hostfile generation
  hosts: all
  become: true

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Gather facts from ALL hosts (regardless of limit or tags)
      setup:
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      delegate_facts: True
      when: hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4'] is not defined
      with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"

  tasks:
    - template:
        src: "templates/hosts.j2"
        dest: "/etc/hosts"
      tags:
        - hostfile

     ...
```

Comment: you must  add :   tags: always         to run pre-task regardless tags.  But well done !!!! very useful.

Answer (score 12):

In general the way to get facts for all hosts even when you don't want to run tasks on all hosts is to do something like this:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks: [ ]
```

But as you mentioned, the --limit parameter will limit what hosts this would be applied to.

I don't think there's a way to simply tell Ansible to ignore the --limit parameter on any plays.  However there may be another way to do what you want entirely within Ansible.

I haven't used it personally, but as of Ansible 1.8 [fact caching](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching) is available. In a nutshell, with fact caching enabled Ansible will use a redis server to cache all the facts about hosts it encounters and you'll be able to reference them in subsequent playbooks:

> With fact caching enabled, it is possible for machine in one group to reference variables about machines in the other group, despite the fact that they have not been communicated with in the current execution of /usr/bin/ansible-playbook.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
That was our first solution as well, but it seems fact caching is the only solution for this problem as of yet. It would be nice to have something that can override the limit-parameter for gathering facts.

Answer (score 6):

This still seems to be an issue without a clean solution here in 2016, but newer versions of Ansible offer a "jsonfile" fact caching backend, which seems to be a decent compromise to installing Redis locally just to address this need. Now I just fire off an `ansible all -m setup` before running a playbook with the `--limit` option. Good enough for jazz!

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your playbook to:

```
...
- hosts: "{{ limit_hosts|default('default_group') }}"
  tasks:
    ...
...
```

And when you run it, if `some_var` is not defined (normal state) then it will run on the `default_group` inventory group, BUT if you run it as:

```
ansible-playbook --extra-vars "limit_hosts=myHost" myplaybook.yml
```

Then it will only run on your `myHost`, but you could still have other sections with different `hosts: ..` declarations, for fact gathering, or anything else actually.

Comment: this is duplication of groups and -l parameter.
```[db:children]
something-DB
```
group your stuff and use groups.