# Read Ansible variables of another group

Tags: ansible

Here is an example of inventory file:

```
[web_servers]
web_server-1 ansible_ssh_host=xxx ansible_ssh_user=yyy

[ops_servers]
ops_server-1 ansible_ssh_host=xxx ansible_ssh_user=zzz
```

Furthermore, `web_servers` group has specific vars in `group_vars/web_servers`:

```
tomcat_jmx_port: 123456
```

How can I access `tomcat_jmx_port` var when dealing with `ops_servers` ?

Some will probably say I need a commun ancessor group (like `all`) to put common vars, but this is just an example, in true life there are many vars I want to access from `ops_servers`, and I want to keep things clear so `tomcat_jmx_port` have to stay in `web_servers` group_vars file.

In fact, I need a kind of local lookup.

Any idee ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14):

To access variables from an arbitrary group you'd use the global variable `groups` which gives you access to all the vars of the hosts in the group.  So something like this would return the name of the first host in the `web_servers` group:

```
{{ groups['web_servers'][0] }}
```

To access the individual variables of a host you would do something like this:

```
{{ hostvars['somehost']['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}
```

This would return the default IP address of the host named `somehost`.

You can easily combine `hostvars` & `groups` if you need something more complex:

```
{{ hostvars[groups['web_servers'][0]]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}
```

This one will give you the default IP address of the first host in your `web_servers` group.

Comment: Your response is correct, I already knew this solution (`{{ groups['web_servers'][0] }}`) but it looks like a hack :/ Nothing better to simply parse `group_vars` files ?

Comment: No, this is the proper way to access variables.  It takes into account [variable precedence](http://goo.gl/rvEBDa), which is something to be aware of.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work if you only deploy `ops_servers` (since Ansible do not compute `groupvars` of `web_servers` hosts)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024664/force-fact-gathering-on-all-hosts) covers what you're running into and how to address it.

Comment: Thanks for the link but I don't like this solution: it could happen long time before deploying again `web_servers`, so `web_servers`'s hosts `facts` could be flushed when I deploy `ops_servers`. You'll be right if you say flush time can be changed but it seems this feature is not designed for long time fact caching.

Answer (score 9):

You can also "include" the variables in the run context using

```
- include_vars: group_vars/web_servers
```

Notice that if you have variables with the same name in the context they will be overwritten.

This will make your variable available as {{ tomcat_jmx_port }}

Comment: Ahaa, that's a pretty cool solution, I did not think about it. It's not perfect because all vars of `web_servers` file will also be included but I prefer this to `{{ groups['web_servers'][0] }}` because there is no need to have a host in the group. Thanks !

Comment: The perfect solution (the one I'm looking for) is the one which allows me to only pick one var value of `web_servers` file

Comment: Yeah, the only other way I can think on how approach that is to have nested groups, where you have web_servers and ops_servers part of a bigger group called servers for example and there you placed just the shared properties

Comment: Yep, that's what I do currently. But I think it's not clean since a ops_server don't have to inherit tomcat jmx conf (in the exemple).